# Twitch TMI, extract all users

Tags: regex, perl, extract, text-mining, twitch

I'm trying to extract all the user names from the source (https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/twitchpresents/chatters), but so far I'm only able to get like the first "name". 
Goal is to get all the names into an array, and then just remove the "viewers", "admins", "staff", etc. names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @listusers = userlist();
sub userlist {
    my $url = "https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/twitchpresents/chatters";
    my $array = get($url);
    my @array2;
    my $time = 0;

    while ($time != 2){
       my $mylist = (join "",grep(/"\s*(.*?)\s*"/, $array[$time])) =~ /"\s*(.*?)\s*"/;
       print $1;
       $time++;
    }
    return @array2;

}

print @listusers;
```

Comment: Oh, I see. You should `push(@array2, $1)` inside the loop. And, $mylist only gets the match result bool. So, if $mylist, then print and store $1.

Comment: It is valid JSON - so IMHO better to use some JSON parser.

Comment: This code does not compile as posted. `$array[$time]` should be `$array->[$time]` as it's an arrayref. Then: Why return an array `@array2` if it's got nothing in it? Or, conversely, why do all that code if you're returning `my @array2` anyway :P. On top of that: yes, do use a parser for JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you get the page with `get` from [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.31/lib/LWP/Simple.pm). Please always show relevant includes.

Since this is valid JSON, use a module for that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use LWP::Simple;    
use JSON;

my $data_json = get($url);

my $data = JSON->new->decode($data_json);
#dd $data;

my @names = @{ $data->{chatters}{moderators} };             # get "moderators"
say "@names";
# my @all_names = map { @$_ } values %{$data->{chatters}};  # or get all names
```

This prints the line:   `cliccer cuda hnlbot nixi93 scorpy0 somppe`

I print "names" of *moderators* as an example of getting one category out; the commented out line gets all names in one array. Once you have a hashref there are various ways to extract what you need.

Your code seems to be trying to parse that JSON string. It is very easy with a module.

One can view complex data structures with [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) or such. I use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm).

Here [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.97000/lib/JSON.pm) is used, which delegates to [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm) if installed or to the "pure Perl" (and slower) [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-PP-2.97001/lib/JSON/PP.pm) otherwise. Another option is [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/Cpanel-JSON-XS-3.0239/XS.pm).

---

For convenience, the structure printed by `dd $data` is

```
{
  _links => {},
  chatter_count => 15,
  chatters => {
    admins      => [],
    global_mods => [],
    moderators  => [
                     "cliccer",
                     "cuda",
                     "hnlbot",
                     "joffy95",
                     "nixi93",
                     "scorpy0",
                     "somppe",
                   ],
    staff       => [],
    viewers     => [
                     "coldblood94",
                     "coldbot",
                     "gabenator",
                     "gharokk",
                     "reconcrusadershadow",
                     "scrubnubslulz",
                     "shai_the_panda",
                     "sonadourge",
                   ],
  },
}
```

Comment: or using [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo): `perl -Mojo -E 'my $d=j( g(q{https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/twitchpresents/chatters})->body );say "@$_" for @{$d->{chatters}}{qw(moderators viewers)}'`

Comment: @jm666 Sure :) But they went with `LWP::Simple` so I kept that approach

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use
[`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent)
for this, as it contains a JSON decoder as well as an HTTP user agent and makes the code much more concise

I assume you want the names of all the different categories of *chatters* so that's what the `map` statement does: simply flattening all of the categories—`admins`, `global_mods`, `moderators`, `staff`, and `viewers`—into a single list

If anything goes wrong with the HTTP transfer then the subroutine will simply return an empty list, so you may want to add some proper error handling

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my @list_users = chatters();
say for @list_users;

sub chatters {

    my $url = 'https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/twitchpresents/chatters';
    return unless my $data = Mojo::UserAgent->new->get($url)->res->json;

    map { @$_ } values %{ $data->{chatters} };
}
```

#### output

```
girlonduty
moobot
ravager
100tesports
123mickeypr
13eebo
13urnxcalibur
2dmoody
2l33t
2tony79
3nticed
...
```